# How did we get saddled with the (hierarchical) filesystem as the basic data structure?

Tags: language-agnostic, operating-systems, data-structures

I'm self-taught and I don't have a CS degree. The more I've been learning about data structure, the more I wonder, in this day and age, how are we still saddled with the filesystem, with directories and files, as the basic data storage structure on the OS?

I understand the simplicity of it, but it seems nowadays that there could be more options available natively. As far as I'm aware, the only project to improve the basic functionality of the filesystem was ReiserFS, where you could tell what line of a file was changed by whom, and when.

For instance, if I could have native tagging for files, where I could tag images, diagrams, word-processing documents, an entire code repository, all as belonging to a single project, that would really be helpful to me. Since I'm stuck in the filesystem paradigm, I know that I could put all those into a single folder/directory, but what if they already exist in disparate directories, and they need to stay there? I know there are programs out there that can do this, but why aren't they on the filesystem?

Something that would be nice to have is some kind of relational feature in the filesystem, like you get with RDBMSes. I understand that that was supposed to be part of Vista/7, but that fell off the feature list too.

Sure, any program can store a binary file and have any data structure it wants in it, by why couldn't the OS offer more complex ways of storing data, beyond the simple heirarchy of the filesystem?

Comment: This should probably be on SuperUser

Comment: The core of it should be simple. The optional bloat you mention should go on top of a simple core. Alternatively, wait two decades and someone will reinvent the notion of a file system.

Comment: "what if they already exist in disparate directories, and they need to stay there?" Sometimes you can use hard-links to solve this problem...

Comment: Also, some interesting reading on the topic: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?FileSystemAlternatives

Comment: Not really a solution in Windows 7 but the new Libraries can give you some of the functionality you seem interested in: http://lifehacker.com/#!5464350/get-to-know-windows-7-libraries-inside-and-out

Comment: Short answer: It ain't broke.

Comment: Windows (Vista) does have "tags" for certain file types (.docx, .jpg, and other media files).

Comment: If I want to put a file into two different folders at once, I put a shortcut to that file in one. The disadvantage is that if you relocate that folder/file, the shortcut will be invalid.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Start with this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_File_System

Read this: http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix/history_timeline.html

Then read this: [http://www.amazon.com/UNIX-Filesystems-Evolution-Design-Implementation/dp/0471164836](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471164836)

There's a simple answer to "why couldn't the OS offer more complex ways of storing data, beyond the simple heirarchy of the filesystem?"

Because it's too much for the OS to do.

That's what libraries and application packages are for.

Oracle, for example, will sell you a file-system-like set of features that you manage with the Oracle toolset.

Python uses the DBM library to create very sophisticated on-disk storage structures.

CouchDB and Mongo (and others) are very sophisticated storage structures that offer some database-like features.

The point is that the OS should do the minimum and everything is an add-on.

Comment: Quite agree. Actually, a lot of what OP was asking for is present in the eaither dead or dying WinFS project: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinFS. As much as the geek in says, 'Neat!' the experienced user and software engineer in me says, "Trying way too hard!"

Comment: "The point is that the OS should do the minimum and everything is an add-on." Quite a bold statement in an age where some operating systems contain a built-in windowing system, file indexing service, media player, remote desktop, firewall or Netris.

Comment: @biziclop: Agreed.  Windows has diverged from the Linux viewpoint.  Nothing surprising there.

Comment: @S.Lott Don't get me wrong, I agree with your approach, but Windows is saddled with so much useless rubbish anyway, one extra feature won't make a difference. :)

Comment: @biziclop: It's not my "approach".  It's a summary of the above links.  Windows has diverged from the Linux viewpoint.  One extra feature was apparently impossible to implement, as evidenced by the death of the Longhorn project.

Comment: That is the Unix philosophy. It is not necessarily right. It does (and a C complier) make Unix easy to port to hardware. It also makes it simple enough for people to clone Unix into the flavours of -ix likes we find today. If a feature is useful, and all programs need it, like say, spell checked input fields, then there is value in having the runtime environment provide it. We don't need 400 independent versions of a ribbon bar.

Comment: @Tim Williscroft: "right" is not the issue.  History is the issue.  The reasons are historical.  "If a feature is useful, ... there is value in having the runtime environment provide it".  Correct.  But that does **not** mean OS.  That means libraries or applications.  Which is the easy way to do it, and the historical precedent.

Comment: @S.Lott (Right is subjective and not the OP's Q, but if nobody makes value judgements, we have no values to share) The difference from a user or application programmers point of view between runtime and OS is.... zero. Can anyone really argue that Unix ioctl() is anything but a hack to avoid adding methods to files? Application code ends up needing to know the details of hardware. Good for kernel developers, bad for applications programmers (which there are a lot more of).

Comment: Thats all fine for unix. Ever used an IBM mainframe with TSO? Partitioned Data Sets... basically a huge flat system on a disk volume with files on. A PDS allowed files-inside-files, but only one level of. Hierarchies depend on where you go looking. Some systems dont have them, still.

Comment: @S.Lott It isn't black and white like that. A small, modular OS has a lot of advantages, that's true. It also spawns miriads of slightly different solutions to the same problem. As it indeed has done in the Linux world. A more bulky, feature-rich OS can do away with those variations that make life hell sometimes. The problem isn't specific to OSs, this dilemma comes up in every software generic enough.

Comment: @biziclop: "A more bulky, feature-rich OS can do away with those variations that make life hell sometimes"  Do you have an example of this?  Windows is a lot of variations that are wildly incompatible with each other and only share a common brand name.  Look at all the installs which require a specific service pack of a specific version of Windows.  Bulky OS's don't seem to escape from the myriads of slightly different solutions.

Comment: @S.Lott Well, that's because Windows is crap. :) Like I said, this dilemma isn't limited to operating systems either. But I'll raise you FreeBSD.

Comment: @biziclop: My point remains this: "A more bulky, feature-rich OS" is certainly possible.  It may even be desirable.  That doesn't matter.  What matters is the reason why we have a very simple hierarchical file system.  That reason is the historical precedent of keeping the OS as small as possible.  Other considerations -- while valid -- aren't answers to this question.

Comment: @S.Lott History, as always, only gives half the answer. It will tell you how and why tree-based file systems were invented. It won't explain why we're still using them. After all, many different ways of organising files existed histoically, yet one of them outgrew all the rest. Why this one, why not the others? Or why not something new? You won't find the answer in history.

Comment: @biziclop: "Or why not something new?"  That's still not part of this question.  Other things may be possible or desirable, but that's not part of **this** question.

Comment: @S.Lott Then I think you should read the question again. Not only is it part of the question, it **is** the question itself. "in this day and age, how are we **still** saddled with the filesystem"

Comment: @biziclop: Again.  The answer is "history".  Other technologies are possible or even desirable.  But the reason we are still saddled is history.

Comment: @S.Lott In that case I think you don't understand what "reason" means. If what you say was a valid argument, we'd all be single-celled organisms. Because well, our ancestors in history were, so we can't be anything else either. It's more likely though that you're just reluctant to admit that you misunderstood the question.

Comment: @biziclop: I don't want to address alternatives or futures or better ideas.  I only want to answer the question, which was "why?"  Why is history.  The future is a separate question.  Alternatives are a separate question.  If you want to address alternatives and futures, please either ask a separate question or post a separate answer.  I want to focus on this question.  To which the answer is "history".

Comment: @S.Lott You've just answered the wrong question (well, half the question at best) and now you insist that the question wasn't what it was. We've all misread questions, why not admit it? "how are we **still** saddled with the filesystem?" is asking exactly why no alternative route was taken. And your answer is: because it wasn't. Well, brilliant. :)

Comment: @biziclop: We're still saddled with it because of history.  It's really just that simple.  There's little more to say except that we have a long history of working this way.  That's the reason why we haven't improved or changed.  History.  Just that.  Nothing more.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is : Everyday people understand the file system. It reminds them of a file Cabinet. Think about web pages and even Fat apps, why do you think `Tabs` are so popular? People can identify with them, and understand them quickly.

Imaging trying to teach Grandma to search a DB for File based on property tags.. With the file system,  **Grandma knows the file is simply where she Put it**.

Even with WinFS I don't think MS was going to get rid of the file system look and feel.

Comment: I have to disagree with this.  Most people who aren't forced to navigate the filesystem don't do it.  They open a word processor and click their recent document, or search in Windows 7's start menu, etc.  And lots of people lose track of where they put their files.  It would be a lot easier for Grandma to search "cookie recipes" or "grandson photos" or whatever than to maintain a folder hierarchy.

Comment: This assumes she was properly tagged her files.. What if she just wants to "Look for them"? The File system acts and menu sub-menu system as well.

Comment: For most things the plain text and present metadata like music tags are enough.  I think filling in the rest is just as easy as naming and filing things, and doesn't require you to remember where they are. Plus we are getting to the point where the computer can recognize who's in pictures and that sort of thing.

Comment: This might come as a shock for you: everyday people don't understand the file system. They haven't got the faintest of ideas. And I don't mean a Unix style FS with its mount points, symlinks and hardlinks, but a bog standard directory structure with files in it.

Comment: @Morons, my grandmother never knows where she puts things. Gmail already has shifted my desired paradigm to a tagging system, especially with filters to automatically tag things. I think the filesystem paradigm was implemented largely due to the simplicity of programming tree-structures. It also makes addressing easier from a programming perspective. How would you specify a document's location in a tag-based system? Not saying it can't be done, but the details need to be ironed out.

Comment: Do you purchase your file cabinets full of thousands of folders and documents necessary to the operation of the cabinet itself, which you must navigate through and around but be careful not to touch?  Does your file cabinet seem to open to a different location every time you pull out the drawer? Etc. etc.  I agree with Matthew and biziclop - "Everyday" people *don't* get it.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that everyone knows how to use it, or that it imitates real life. In real life, you can put more than one manilla folder in another. And everyday users store all their documents either on the desktop or in My Documents, and before windows, everything was in the C:\ root :P

Comment: Everydat people don't get it. But they "get" a tagged attribute system even less. Everyday people REALLY STRUGGLE with all these ideas, because they involve rules. And the rules are things they find hard to remember. they just want to do stuff and anything at all that you do that tries to organise things gets in the way of doing stuff. (And yes I am very well aware that this creates a self-fulfilling prophesy).

Comment: I have a CS degree. But I don't know into which folders any Windows does put what files into. Especially Desktop, StartMenu, QuickLaunch, and all the other user/system specific default folders. (That M$-Help system does not help in explaining to me how to press a button.) I need to install CygWin to be able to search for my own files, because newer M$ search features do not find simple existing files anymore like on win2k. Disabling misfeatures like hide-system-files, hide-file-extensions don't solve most problems anymore. I gave up Windows, when I was forced to work on the (brand new) winXP.

Comment: @biziclop Which century are you from? (Not born in, but currently in.) If your defintion of "everyday people" doesn't include people ages 13 to 30, I suppose you may be somewhere close to not entirely remotely correct.

Comment: My mom stores all her photos in one single folder, and sorts them by dates. So when she wants to find some photo, she goes to a specific year and month, then she looks through it in the gallery. And this is all she remembers: the rough estimate on the date the picture has been taken. When I once moved her files to a new directory and all the date informations has been lost, she couldn't find anything anymore :P File systems? What's even that?! :q

Answer (score 8):

There's a little truth in every answer here but I don't think it's the whole truth.

What you list are mostly features that are sorely missed every day by users and developers alike.

People don't understand the tree-based file system any more than they would understand a DAG-based one.

And there's absolutely no excuse for the pathetic appendages of file names called extensions. They are not only completely unsuitable for their purpose (identifying the file type) but also an endless source of nuisance for users.

The reason we're still using them is a mixture of a "that'll do" attitude and the real need to maintain compatibility with older code. A new approach to storing files would mean a radical change in basic file I/O API, rendering most existing code useless. Either that or you have to tiptoe around them, maintaining the legacy API. Remember PROGRA~1.

I think for the reasons above, although the future could hold more specialised file systems for special applications, but while the desktop and laptop PC architectures of present survive, we're stuck with the largely tree-based file system with its lack of metadata and its horrible little extensions.

---

Now I'm going to switch sides.

Because it's all around us, we never really appreciate how mind-bogglingly powerful the tree metaphor is. On my hard drive I've got several hundred thousand files. If I have to find one, it rarely takes more than a minute, even if I know very little about the file. Now imagine the same task without any structure, just a flat list of names, scrolling endlessly.

Yet all the operations are straightforward, there's no spooky action at a distance, nothing that would make me go wtf.

Actually, I did implement a document store with rich metadata and a DAG-based hierarchy once. (It wasn't even a free-form DAG, it was strictly a two-level metastructure and the documents, which could be children of either a level 1 or a level 2 collection. So it's really simple.)

Obviously, the requirement that document names should be unique within a collection had to stay.

And then the problems started to flow. What if you open a collection and change the name of the document to something that clashes in a different collection the document also belongs to? We displayed an error message but the users were completely baffled. (These are the very same users who had asked for this requirement.)

They tried to delete a document, but all that did was remove it from the collection. So it still showed up in search results. We tried it the other way around too, but then they were complaining that they deleted a document from collection A and it magically disappeared from collection B. So we needed both an "unlink" and a hard delete operation.

Eventually we conceded defeat, fortunately still in time.

The extra search facets the metadata made possible worked an absolute treat though.

Comment: Rememebr CP/M on a 5 MB hard drive? Hundreds and hundreds of files scrolling past. AWFUL!

Comment: @quickly_now Ah, the good old CP/M. :)

Comment: I think the part about deleting vs unlinking touches on one of the biggest factors here: *location* is a very pervasive metaphor, because it's something we use all the time in the real world. However hard you try to tell users that a view "finds" their documents rather than "contains" them, they _will_ re-invent that metaphor, and think of the document as being "in" that location. The idea of "your document is in exactly two places, and unlinking from both will erase it from the disk" doesn't match anything in every day experience. So metadata always comes _on top of_ location, not _instead_.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I barely touch metadata on my files on the Mac. I think in the last 5 years of using OSX (which supports comments and so forth), I've used metadata on maybe 2 files. Not saying it's a bad idea.

I'm just not sure how the overhead of tagging is pragmatic for me.

I think the nicest filesystem feature that I know of would be a filesystem level versioning system... that works cross partitions.  It was done on VAXen in the 70s and early 80s, not sure why it didn't catch on with Unix and NTFS/Windows.

Comment: Modern versions of NTFS/Windows *do* offer versioning. It's not exactly in-your-face, but it does exist. Can't say how it compares to VMS though.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked with non-hierarchical file systems on older minis like HP3000 and Encore/Gould.  You didn't have directories; you had a group and an account, and files were named as "*group* . *account* . *file*", like "users.jbode.myfile1", "dev.jbode.main", etc.

Now, these are *old* systems, where individual disk space quotas were in the single megabytes, so it's not like you needed too many levels to organize your stuff, but from a user's and programmer's perspective hierarchical systems are *much* nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where (at least some) current file systems really need to do much [Edit: anything, to be honest] to support tags. When you get down to it, supporting tags means little more than some extra data associated *with* a file, but isn't written into the stream of bytes *for* that file.

NTFS (to choose one example that's in *wide* use) can do that just fine: as far as NTFS cares, a file isn't necessarily a single stream of bytes. On NTFS you can associate an arbitrary number of streams of data with a single file name. Each file has a (possibly empty) "primary stream" that doesn't have a name. It can also, however, have an arbitrary number of other streams, each of which must have a name. Using this, it would be truly *trivial* to add a stream named (just for example) "tags" to an existing file, and (obviously enough) write your tags to that stream.

After that comes the somewhat more difficult part: getting your tools to make use of the tags you put there. Ideally, you'd probably want to index them for fast searching, so you'd be able to do things like create a "virtual directory" of all the files with a specific tag.

At least from my perspective, the file system already has what's needed though -- it's supposed to store and retrieve the data, and it can do that perfectly well right now. Making use of that data is the job of other tools. Those tools don't currently exist, but the file system infrastructure to support them does.

If I'm allowed to be cynical for a moment, I'd say it was inevitable that this feature of NTFS would remain almost completely ignored and unknown. After all, it's simple to use and doesn't require any special API or anything else. You can use it quite nicely in completely portable C, C++, or anything else that will let you specify an arbitrary file name. Here's a quick bit of code to demonstrate creating a file with an AFS:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream out("test.txt");
    std::ofstream tag("test.txt:tags");

    out << "This is the output file";
    tag << "tag1 tag2";

    return 0;
}
```

And, here's some code to read and display the tags:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() { 
    std::ifstream tags("test.txt:tags");

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(tags),
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

All very simple and easy. Note that although I've only written a trivial bit of data there, you can treat an AFS just like any other file -- all the usual "stuff" works just like with anything else. In a normal directory display, all that will show up is the primary stream (e.g., the size shown for the file will be the size of the primary stream), but if you want to see it, `dir` *can* show information about alternate streams as well with the `/R` flag. For example, a listing for the file created above looks like this:

```
03/16/2011  08:22 PM                23 test.txt
                                     9 test.txt:tags:$DATA
               1 File(s)             23 bytes
```

Comment: DIR might be able to show it, but backup of a file with alternate streams is **horribly difficult**, especially to some other system. For example most NAS drives today use Linux, and the file systems there don't handle alternate streams at all. Copy the file over... and all the alt stuff just disappears.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that most NAS systems are rather...challenged (and this isn't the only way either). For actual backup and restore kinds of things, it doesn't cause a problem though (at least if the software in question is competently written at all): `BackupRead` will serialize all the streams, and `BackupWrite` will reconstitute the file (with alternate streams) from the serialized format.

Comment: Depends if you want the backed-up files to be directly readable on the NAS. If you do (and avoid the need for special restore programs) then you are stuck with plain-ole files.